# mongodb articles.length undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, pug

I am building a nodejs, express, mongodb blog, with jade.

My folder structure is:
project/
        modules/
          views/
                index.jade
        app.js
        articleprovider-memory.js
        articleprovider-mongodb.js

when I run node app.js through console and go to the localhost port I get the TypeError:

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at jade.debug.unshift.lineno...

In browser. Possibly referring to an anonymous function.

Here is the Articleprovider-memory.js

```
ArticleProvider.prototype.save = function(articles, callback) {
  var article = null;

  if( typeof(articles.length)=="undefined")
    articles = [articles];

  for( var i =0;i< articles.length;i++ ) {
    article = articles[i];
    article._id = articleCounter++;
    article.created_at = new Date();

    this.dummyData[this.dummyData.length]= article;
  }
  callback(null, articles);
};

/* Lets bootstrap with dummy data */
new ArticleProvider().save([
  {title: 'Post one', body: 'Body one', comments:[{author:'Bob', comment:'I love it'}, {author:'Dave', comment:'This is rubbish!'}]},
  {title: 'Post two', body: 'Body two'},
  {title: 'Post three', body: 'Body three'}
], function(error, articles){});

exports.ArticleProvider = ArticleProvider;
```

articleprovider-mongodb.js

```
ArticleProvider = function(host, port) {
  this.db= new Db('node-mongo-blog', new Server(host, port, {auto_reconnect: true}, {}));
  this.db.open(function(){});
};

ArticleProvider.prototype.save = function(articles, callback) {
    this.getCollection(function(error, article_collection) {
      if( error ) callback(error)
      else {
        if( typeof(articles.length)=="undefined")
          articles = [articles];

        for( var i =0;i< articles.length;i++ ) {
          article = articles[i];
          article.created_at = new Date();
        }

        article_collection.insert(articles, function() {
          callback(null, articles);
        });
      }
    });
};

exports.ArticleProvider = ArticleProvider;
```

And this is my route:

```
var articleProvider = new ArticleProvider('localhost', 27017);

app.get('/', function(req, res){    
    articleProvider.findAll( function(error,docs){        
        res.render('index.jade', {title: 'Blog', articles:docs});
            })
res.render('index.jade')
});
```

then the index.jade file

```
// extends layout

block content
h1= title
 #articles
    - each article in articles
      div.article
        div.created_at= article.created_at
        div.title 
            a(href="/blog/"+article._id.toHexString())!= article.title
        div.body= article.body
```

I've read a lot about all of the dependencies, but am still new to them. From what I can gather any of these could be the problem, if I am right do tell me with a detailed remedy.

1. My index.jade code is incorrect
2. index.jade is referring to an array and my articles object is not an array
3. mongodb does not have a proper connection established to the app
4. I need to be using monk but I'm not

some of my code comes from this article
http://howtonode.org/express-mongodb

Thankyou in advance

Comment: Why are you rendering index.jade twice in your route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1. Fix the express route

Your route is having multiple `render` calls. It should be modified to.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){    
    articleProvider.findAll( function(error,docs){        
        res.render('index.jade', {title: 'Blog', articles:docs});
    })
});
```

#### 2. Check `articles` is defined in jade view before looping

In the jade view before traversing the articles array, make sure it is defined already.

with

```
block content
h1= title
 #articles
    - if(typeof(article) !== 'undefined')
       - each article in articles
         div.article
           div.created_at= article.created_at
           div.title 
               a(href="/blog/"+article._id.toHexString())!= article.title
           div.body= article.body
```

#### 3. Handle the error parameter in mongo query

Also you have consider the `error` variable available in the callback. So that if any error occurred while querying mongo then that could be handled. Like

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){    
    articleProvider.findAll( function(error,docs){  

        if(error) {
              console.log("mongo db error"+error);
              docs = [];
        }

        res.render('index.jade', {title: 'Blog', articles:docs});

    })
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I was not as careful in my error checking when I neared my final compilation of my code.